# TestCafe Error: "No tests to run. Either the test files contain no tests or the filter function is too restrictive"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, automated-tests, testcafe

I want to perform automated testing with **TestCafe**, but I got this error while testing with the following command.

```
testcafe chrome testc.ts
```

I used this command for testing the **testc.ts** file in my **Angular application** and I installed TestCafe globally on my project.

I have the latest **Angular CLI, node and npm.**

Here is a screenshot of my test code and the command used to run TestCafe:

[image: Screenshot of my code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you didn't pass the right path to the file. Try this:

```
testcafe chrome src/testc.ts
```